# What difference does it make to implement a feature as policy service vs as milter in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, email-server, milter, e-mailrelay

I am trying to implement MTA using Postfix. I am struck at how to implement standard services like SPF, DKIM etc. as well as some custom services. They can either be implemented as policy delegation service and called by `check_policy_service` or as `smtpd` milters, but I am confused which method will be more appropriate and why.

I see policy service will give more flexibility in terms of where I can apply it. Also the documentation says policy services also enjoy wider action list like `Defer`, `Dunno` which are not available to milter actions. But there should be some distinct advantages that milter's implementation offer. I'd like a comparison between these two types of implementation.

Answer (score 5):

For most purposes, including basic message authentication checks (SPF,  DMARC, BIMI, ..), [either interface is suitable](https://www.postfix.org/CONTENT_INSPECTION_README.html). For content checking (blocking unwanted attachment), signatures (DKIM, ARC) and such, you need an interface that gives you that information, such as the milter one.

**The interfaces *do* offer most features and basic actions**, namely both can:

1. investigate the sending address, name and envelope information
2. permanently reject (code 5XX) or temporarily defer (code 4XX a.k.a "tempfail"), with optionally custom smtp status code, extended status code, and (possibly multi-line) smtp status text.
3. receive additional configuration: `milter_macro_v`/`policy_context`
4. prepend message headers (a popular choice would be `Authentication-Results:`)
5. schedule a message for silent discarding or quarantine despite signalling acceptance

The interface also **share some limitations**, though specifics differ:

1. your software must not malfunction on multi-recipient messages
2. your software needs to get IDN handling right. (those lovely `xn--` A-labels in domains)
3. partly by their nature, partly by design, *neither* interface permits graceful handling local maildrop (non-SMTP-submissions) in all the same ways you could handle SMTP submissions.
4. your software needs to *get stuff done* while the sender is waiting - expensive processing, network lookups or unreliable checks must at some point be interrupted, the message deferred, and measures taken so it finishes *in time* next time.

**Unique for milter interface**

The milter interface allows you to parse, and selectively remove or rewrite arbitrary headers, or message body (parts). However, editing is possibly better done in post-queue processing, past address-rewriting and multi-recipient pitfalls.

In any case, message syntax and encoding features must not not make your software misbehave. Think of the notoriously difficult-to-parse *address headers* and attachment filenames. I have yet to encounter software that gets this 100% right.

You want to use the milter interface if you need to act on non-default SMTP commands, or care about SMTP session state transitions. In the milter interface, you get to handle things like `RSET` and (must) handle your local state accordingly - where in the policy interface postfix sends you what you need with the *effective* `protocol_state`.

Beware: the milter interface *documentation* is far from clear on where Postfix aims for sendmail [bug-compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug_compatibility), and where it deviates. Also, the header hook was broken in the past (in by now unsupported releases).

Milters signals their final decisions to postfix by (if using the C library) returning fixed `SMFIS_*` codes (e.g. `SMFIS_TEMPFAIL` for deferral), but may precede that to with a `smfi_setreply(…, "4XX", "4.X.X", text)` call to customize the return.

**Unique to policy daemon interface**

You may choose the order between restriction classes and your daemon - that is much more versatile than just ordering milters against other milters.

You want to use the the policy interface if you need to return non-SMTP results, such as `defer_if_permit` or your custom `smtpd_restriction_classes`. Cases where you will need this include the performance motivated need skip some checks for very busy servers. E.g. when your policy must be, rather than being the final arbiter of what can be accepted or not, merely select a message *class* to be processed in additional checks or routing decisions.

Policy daemons signal their final decisions to postfix via textual actions and their arguments, if applicable, e.g. `action=DEFER optional text...` (which is a fancier way of saying `action=450 4.7.1 optional text...`)

Comment: I am really new to it can you please explain how can milter defer an email, as per the documentation milter's fail is basically reject with temporary eror while quarantine move the mail to hold queue and not defer queue.

Comment: @SUNITAGUPTA Can you rephrase that? I am not sure whether you are surprised by the fact Postfix documentation distinguishes *tempfail* & *defer* where sendmail used the term *tempfail* for both policy and error results, or whether you are surprised that *before-queue* deferral means this happens before entering a local queue ;)

Comment: In postfix documentation it mentions under milter default actions "tempfail
Reject all further commands in this session with a temporary status code."